# Homomorphisms S4 to Z

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Find all homomorphisms f: S4 -> Z.

I know that Ker(f) must be a normal subgroup in S4. So, Ker(f) must be {e}, V4, A4 or S4.
However, I don't know how to use this information.
Thanks.

Comment: $S_4$ is torsion; $\Bbb Z$ is torsion-free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one such homomorphism, the zero homomorphism (mapping everything to 0).

The reason is there every non-zero element of $\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite order, and the order of the image (under a homomorphism) of any element of finite order must be finite.

Comment: Moreover, this argument works for every finite group, not just $S_4$.